# What's the proper way to publish an electron app into Nexus

Tags: npm, electron, nexus3, electron-packager

I have an electron app that needs to run on multiple architectures.
I use electron-packager to make a distribution folder.

I originally tried to npm publish this folder to a nexus repo.
npm publish strips the node_modules out of the built app which would make it break. As far as I can tell, there is no way to stop it from doing so.

Does anyone know the path I should be taking?

I am new to electron AND nexus so take my analysis with a grain of salt